# Mobile date input element receiving click but not launching date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have a scenario where I want to click a "hidden" (0 width, 0 height) input of type=date when clicking on another element (essentially a styled input/select element). There's a little more to the component but the crux is this:

```
<Container flexDirection="column" onClick={handleClick}>
     <StyledInput
          type="date"
          name="date"
          ref={inputField}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          value={moment(values[name]).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
          data-test={props['data-test']}
        />
</Container>
```

where handleClick is:

```
const handleClick = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    inputField.current.click();
  };
```

When I log the click events, the input is indeed getting clicked. However, the date picker does not launch. The only way to make it launch is by directly clicking the input, however in this scenario only part of the visible input field is actually clickable. Why is my input not launch its date picker despite receiving the click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that what is needed here is to focus rather than click.

```
const handleClick = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    inputField.current.focus();
  };
```